# sleep() function in PHP

Tags: php, html, sleep

I have a php page where I need to show images from database wait for seconds which again comes from database and show next image respectively.
I tried using `sleep()` function but, it runs the whole seconds and then display all images all at once.
Example:
image1   3 sec
image2   2 sec
so It first needs to displays image1 wait for 3 sec and then image2 for 2 sec and so on
but now it runs for 5 sec and shows both iamge1 and image2
My code :

```
 <div class="box">
            <?
            $select= "select * from filemanager WHERE day='$dayofweek' and ('$curr_time'>=fromTime and '$curr_time'<=toTime)";
            echo $select;
                $res1 =  mysqli_query($con, $select);
                $num = mysqli_num_rows($res1);
                echo $num;
                while ($data1 = $res1->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $file_name=$data1['fileName'];
                    $path='/uploads/mediaFile/'.$file_name;
                    $sec=$data1['seconds'];
                    echo $sec;
            ?>
            <img src="<?echo $path?>" alt="" />
            <?
            sleep($sec);
                }
            ?>
            
        </div>
```

Please advice.
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to instead refactor your code and methodology with some AJAX calls to get more images after a timed interval.

Comment: PHP runs on server, not on the browser. You are just making the PHP request take longer. ;) To add delay to showing images on the clientside, you would need to do it with JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: can you help me with code example, or any link you can share?

Comment: I made a PHP script for a slideshow system once. I didn't want to use any javascript or anything, so I just made the page automatically refresh after a set amount of seconds and made it so the query would get the next picture in line on every reload. (There wasn't a query really in my case, I just used the last modified attribute on the files in a certain folder, and updated that attribute every time the picture was read) - This worked well for me because the pictures were always full-screen and nothing else showed on the page, and pictures could show in the same order every time.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton this might work for me, in my case I need to get it from queries

Answer (score 1):

You want to pause a php-script. The php-script runs at the server.
Pausing the server is a very baaaad idea. :-)

You need a quick server which is able to serve as many requests as possible. Therefore forget the plan and lets make a new one.

You have a **server which serves pictures**. You have a **client which wants these pictures** rotating every seconds. On server-side you need a script (in php) which is called with the number of a specific picture. This script serves the data to the client.

You have several possibilities on client-side:

**(a)** On client side you need a javascript which initiates now and then an AJAX-call to the server-script. It adds the returned picture to the page and waits again for some time.

**(b)** You run a javascript which restarts the client now and then and summs a counter which tells the server-script which picture is next.

Personally I prefer (a) - but that's just my personal choice.

Comment: Even I think ajax might be correct way to go.Can you please help with the code example.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yeah. Thx. I've edited my answer. Too many scripts in it :-)

Comment: Third option (c) is oldschool iframe, with a meta refresh tag to the next image id :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (JS):

```
var img = 1;

function request() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'fetch.php');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            // Something went wrong
        } else {
            var res = xhr.response;
            // res = fetched image
        }
    };
    xhr.send('img=' + img);
    img += 1;
}

setInterval(request, 10000);
```

About *setTimeout* and *setInterval*: https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval